# get previous search result after exiting from the search result page

Tags: javascript

I am using `<a href="#"  onclick="window.history.go(-1); return false;">back</a>` this code to get the previous search result but it show 'Confirm Form Resubmission' and 'ERR_CACHE_MISS'. How to overcome this problem??